# Given $\lambda$ and $A$, find $v$ such that $\lambda = v^{\intercal}Av$

Tags: linear-algebra

If I know the values of $\lambda$ and $A$, how do I find a vector $v$ such that $\lambda = v^{\intercal}Av $?

This isn't a homework question; I just ran into this problem in Real Life and realized I couldn't solve it!

Comment: Nothing special about your $A$?

Comment: Well it's positive definite, if that's necessary to solve it.

Comment: @Cocopuffs A is positive definite and $\lambda$ will be greater than 0. I didn't realize these details would be relevant :) What do you mean by matrix square root? If you add an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @Brian, the devil is often in the details. Most problems in linear algebra only become tractable because there is exploitable structure or symmetry in them...

Comment: If $A$ is a positive definite symmetric matrix then for given $\lambda>0$ the equation $v^TAv=\lambda$ describes an ellipsoid centered at the origin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A$ is positive definite then for any $\lambda>0$ pick any vector $v\not=0$ and compute
$$
c=v^TAv
$$
Then
$$
v\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{c}}
$$
satisfies your equation.

Answer (score 5):

Start with any vector $v$ such that $v^{\intercal}Av\ne0$ and then

$$v\rightarrow\sqrt{c}\ v\ \Longrightarrow\ v^{\intercal}Av\rightarrow c\ v^{\intercal}Av,$$

i.e. you can make the expression take any value.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if $A$ is positive-definite one may compute a Cholesky decomposition
$$ A = U^{\intercal} U$$
where $U$ is an upper triangular matrix, so your equation reduces to
$$||Uv||^2=\lambda $$
Pick any vector $y$ on the $n$-sphere of radius $\sqrt\lambda$, solve
$$Uv=y$$
for $v$ - which should be trivial, since, as I said above, $U$ is upper triangular - and you've found your solution.

Of course this solution is *immensely* more expensive from a computational standpoint, but it has the advantage that it gives you a way to generate *all* possible solutions by varying $y$.